# Remove modelstate error from view after new text input

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm currently working on a website in MVC4 and trying to implement jquery validation.

I added a modelstate to my http post that gives an error if the username thats filled in the model.Username textbox does not exist:

```
ModelState.AddModelError("UsernameNull", "Username does not exist");
```

And the EditorFor & Validation message in my view:

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Username, "Username:")
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Username)

<div class="error-container">
@Html.ValidationMessage("UsernameNull", null, new { @class = "error-container-error" })
</div>
```

It successfully shows the error "Username does not exist" after the post, but the problem is that the error stays on the view page. What I would like to achieve is when new input is typed in the model.Username textbox, that the error dissapears.

Comment: With custom ModelState errors, you need to write JavaScript to test the value yourself, and then remove the error yourself.

Comment: For a start, it needs to be `ModelState.AddModelError("Username", "Username does not exist");` and `@Html.ValidationMessage("Username")` to match the property name. You don't have an input with `name="UsernameNull"` so there is no `.blur()` of `.keyup()` events that can be handled by `jquery.validate.js` to remove the error message. But this is far better handled using the `[Remote]` attribute. [How to: Implement Remote Validation in ASP.NET MVC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808(VS.98).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest taking advantage of **Data Annotation validators**, which enables you to perform validation simply by adding one or more attributes to a class property.

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace MvcApplication.Models
{
    public class MyModel
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "User name is required")]
        [DisplayName("User Name")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }
    }    
}
```

The following controller action redisplays the view when model state contains any errors

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyAction(MyModel model){
    if(!ModelState.IsValid)
        return View();

    // Insert logic here
    //return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Finally in your view you should be able to use

```
<div class="error-container">
    @Html.ValidationMessage("UserName", "*", new { @class = "error-container-error" })
</div>
```

If you try to POST the form with the UserName textbox empty, the validation message defined in your class should be displayed.